# Падает погода Android Studio

Tags: java, json, api

Ребята сильно не бейте, я тут новенький. Не могу понять почему падает приложение при обращении к серверу по api.
Вот Меин.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView cityTemp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cityTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityTemp);



    }
public void pressButton(View view){

    String temp = new Function().temperature();
    cityTemp.setText(temp);
   }
```

А это обращение к серверу

```
public class Function {
public static JsonObject send()  {
    String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kiev&APPID=693bc5884d2a585cdb170d137f0da55a&units=metric";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String A = String.valueOf(response);
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(A);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    return jobject;
}





    public String temperature() {
        JsonObject jsonObject;
        jsonObject = send();
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("main");
        String temp = jsonObject.get("temp").getAsString();
        return temp;
    }
}
```

А вот что пишет;

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.thinx.myweather, PID: 2546
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                            Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
                                                                               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
                                                                               at com.example.thinx.myweather.Function.send(Function.java:29)
                                                                               at com.example.thinx.myweather.Function.temperature(Function.java:52)
                                                                               at com.example.thinx.myweather.MainActivity.pressButton(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Я не прошу помощи в решении, просто ткните носом куда копать.

Comment: Добавлю еще, этот же код в класе функции отлично работает под IDea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

Ошибка выполнения метода по клику, вызванная:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Нельзя выполнять сетевые запросы в основном UI - потоке приложения. Используйте [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) и учитесь читать логи.

Comment: onClick отрабатывает отлично. Это он ругаеться что при нажатии на кнопку выпадает ошибка. А вот за Asynctask спасибо, буду штудировать